# Which database should one use for stats tracking and archiving emails sent via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, statistics, archive

The question has two sides.

1. We host a lot of static files for public download. PDFs, Zips, images, people download thousands of each every day. We track the counters in our MySQL database, with details being tracked in MongoDB (details like where the download came from and when).
2. We send a lot of emails via PHP. Our application tends to send out hundreds of thousands of emails every month, many of which are newsletters, notifications and invitations for projects. These sent emails are saved into out MySQL database with their crucial data serialized (never the body or actual email content, just the headers, recipient, time of sending etc.)

Is MySQL an ok choice for this? Is Mongo? Should we use something else? Right now both our emails archive table and the download stats table are rapidly approaching 2GB each.

Note: The data we store is accessed regularly, so something to store it in and forget about it is out of the question. We use the download stats to notify the authors of the content that their download count has reached X, and we use the email archive to check the delivery status etc and display it to our employees who track this on a regular basis. (we use Sendgrid for delivery metrics)

Comment: +1 Normally I would vote to close which tech is better questions but you came with a clear defined problem.  Hopefully you get answers.

Comment: Thanks, I was careful to avoid vagueness and subjectivity, this is very important to me and I have no idea how else to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mysql can serve your purpose well. it is more flexible for web, for tracking your log you can use mysql `ARCHIVE` db engine. mysql has some different db engine for different purpose. i think archive will be the best fit for your structure.

in recent i manage a mysql database of 60GB. its was high scaled database and performance is good.

Comment: I chose this as the best answer because I like being able to keep it all in one database - the Archive engine serves this purpose well. Thank you. I'll post back if I have any other findings, but for now, this will do. Hearing you have 60GB is very motivational, that should last us a good while.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

There is this rumor going around that MySQL does not scale very well with the number of rows in a table, and that postgres manages large tables much better, in terms of performance. I would definitely prefer to use postgres for an application with huge tables. (However [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/) says that it's more important how you define and use your database, whatever system you choose.)

If you are feeling adventurous and want to do something more modern and distributed, perhaps look into hadoop and hive, which at the same time can also solve the problem of big file storage, but requires you to learn some new things.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that article is applicable to these times much. It's 6 years old, and both MySQL and Postgre have significantly grown since then. We have a couple tables with over a million records, and they handle well, but they store far less data per field than the email archive one - this growth in size is what concernes me

Answer (score 1):

I'll speak to the MongoDB piece a bit.  I assume you are using the MongoDB store to access the data quickly and perhaps for data you can fire and forget, but is nice to have when running your reports.  The key to keeping a MongoDB instance running fast (besides effective, efficient indexes and appropriate queries, of course) is to make sure that your working data set fits into RAM.

The overall data size is less of an issue in terms of performance, it can be many, many times the size of your working set without it being a problem.  Keep an eye on your resident memory size (MMS is your friend there) and be prepared to shard if you start to trend toward the upper bounds of your hardware.

2GB really is not all that large for a Mongo data set, or even for a working data set.  I have seen data sizes running into the multi-terabyte range.  Based on the information you have provided I think your MongoDB choice is fine for the foreseeable future.